# 2 toggle functions into one

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 2 toggle effect that do the same thing...but I want to know how to make it into one toggle so that way one opens and if i click on the other, the one opened closes. Right now they both do their own since there are seperate and also have their own unique class/id:

```
$('.class1').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('#id1').toggle(200);
});

$('.class2').on('click', function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('active');
     $('#id2').slideToggle(200);
});
```

Heres the FIDDLE:

[**TOGGLE to work in one**](http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/zcWJ6/5/)

***Updated**: Is there a way not to do it using 'section'...in reality the other is a div.
 cms wise it will never always be section' thats why i was wondering if there a way to just use class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would give the items common classes so you can work with them all together.

Something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/4L2NK/

```
$('.toggle').click(function(){
    $('.toggle').removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('section:visible').add($(this).next()).toggle(200);
});
```

Comment: Looks good but what if I cant do it on the "section"...I mean i can add the same class for both but does that mean i can do `.sameclass:visible` ...doing this just opens both at the same time..no luck on this

Comment: Yes, you could give all of the toggle-able elements the same class and go off of that as well.

Comment: Im so confuse Im trying to add this setup but the js keeps this: `element.style {
display: none;
}`

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/zcWJ6/8/ its because of the div covering the a tag??

Comment: Yes, since you added the div, `$(this).next()` doesn't work. It would need to be `$(this).parent().next()`. See http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/. You'll need to find the appropriate combination of traversal functions based on your final html.

Comment: Thanks that does make a lot of sense sorry I missed this in my actual code

Comment: $(this).parent().next() is the answer! The only issue left is my active gets lost...if clicking the other and then clicking same, active state gets lost...i'll figure this somehow. But thanks the answer is set.

Answer (score 1):

Jason P's answer was pretty much on the money, but here's another way to do it where all you need to change in the HTML is the link href:

http://jsfiddle.net/davmillar/tqvZh/

HTML:

```
<a href="#id1" class="class1">open me :)</a>            
    <section id="id1">
        Test
    </section>

<a href="#id2" class="class2">open me :)</a>            
    <section id="id2">
        Test
    </section>
```

JS:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    //Figure out which one we're targeting
    var myTarget = $(this).attr('href');
    // Remove 'active' from all buttons besides what you clicked, toggle the class on what you clicked
    $('.active').not(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    // Slide up all containers besides your target, then toggle your target
    $('section').not(myTarget).slideUp(200);
    $(myTarget).slideToggle(200);
});
```

Comment: I need to figure how to do it without using sections since the other is really a div...I updated the fiddle

Comment: In that case, you'd just have to lump all possible ids into the `slideUp` part of the code or unite them all with some other class.

Comment: Thanks! I credited you, but yes Jason answer got it I appreciate your help though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for ONE function to handle all of your expand/collapse something like this with JQuery:

```
<script>
$(".toggled").slideUp();
$(".clickme").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".toggled").slideToggle("fast");
  });
<script>

<div>
    <h3 class = "clickme">Expand</h3>
    <ul class = "toggled">
        <li>Your Stuff Here!</li>

    </ul>
</div>
<div>
    <h3 class = "clickme">Expand 2</h3>
    <ul class = "toggled">
        <li>Your Stuff Here!</li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

You must use class for multiple toggles with the same function.